# Get Rhythmbox debugging info

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, cd, debugging, logs

I'm having a weird problem with Rhythmbox that no one else seems to have. When I pause on any audio CD, I can't get Rhythmbox to play it again. I've tried various workarounds including trying to play next/previous track, trying to manually move the seek bar, etc. but to no avail. When this happens I've no choice but to remove the CD from my drive and insert it again.

There does not seem to be anything weird with my system when this happens, apart from the fact that Rhythmbox isn't playing as it is supposed to. Is there anything I can do to get more info on why Rhythmbox is acting up as such?

Answer (score 3):

You can get plenty of info running Rhythmbox from the command line with the -d flag. This will generate a load of messages that you better log into some text file. Like:

```
rhythmbox -d > /tmp/rb_debug.log 2>&1
```

Then reproduce the error and exit Rhythmbox. You should then post that file (rb_debug.log) to the  [rhythmbox bug-site](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=rhythmbox) explaining what is going wrong.

Comment: In the past, whenever I reported a problem to the Rhythmbox folk they always asked me to send the logs to rhythmbox-devel. Only if it is deemed as bug should it be registered as one.